# slot machine spins multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple slot machine using this [plugin](https://github.com/josex2r/jQuery-SlotMachine), its working fine. but, what I'm trying to do is, is to make another spin base from user input after showing the result. I tried to use for loop but no luck.

Hope you help me.

Thanks.

[SAMPLE CODE](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/xJKbKx)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var machine1 = $('#machine1').slotMachine();
  var machine2 = $('#machine2').slotMachine();
  var machine3 = $('#machine3').slotMachine();
  var machine4 = $('#machine4').slotMachine();
  var machine5 = $('#machine5').slotMachine();

  var arrResult = [];

function onComplete(active){
  arrResult.push(this.active);
  if (arrResult.length === 5) {
      var output = arrResult.join('');
  }
}
  $('button').click(function() {
    result = [];
    machine1.shuffle(10, onComplete);
    machine2.shuffle(15, onComplete);
    machine3.shuffle(20, onComplete);
    machine4.shuffle(25, onComplete);
    machine5.shuffle(30, onComplete);
  });
  });
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. How is the user input supposed to control the spin? Is typing `1` only supposed to spin the first column, for example?

Comment: no sir, if they type 2, the slot machine(all columns) runs, then, after showing the result. it run again..

Comment: Means if user inputs 4 then you will run the slot for 4 times ?

Comment: yes sir.. you can check the sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit crude, but by deincrementing the rolls at the end of each successful slot roll and then running the slots if remaining rolls is > 0, then it works.

```
rolls--;
if(rolls > 0){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    machine1.shuffle(10, onComplete);
    machine2.shuffle(15, onComplete);
    machine3.shuffle(20, onComplete);
    machine4.shuffle(25, onComplete);
    machine5.shuffle(30, onComplete);
  }, 1500);
}
```

[Updated code pen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GBKJda)

Comment: thanks for help sir, it really work, but it can only do 2 spins.

Comment: I see the issue - it has been fixed. Try the updated sample now.

Answer (score 0):

I've setup a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/v05mkqwwr7) to do what you want to do.

A break down of my solution:

1. On mount, convert the div with id "machine" into a slot machine
2. Have a button to trigger the slot machine's spin
3. Have an input element to accept the number of times to spin the slot machine
4. A clear button to clear the results

So say you input 2 into the text input, and click on shuffle. We'll call `slotmachine.shuffle()` with a callback which will store the current result and then spin the slot machine again if `the number of times to shuffle > 0`

The idea is to shuffle, keep track of result and then programatically call shuffle again and keep repeating the process for as many times.

[image: The code in action]